# Fortify Scan issue: Cross-Site Scripting issue when assigning a new URL

Tags: javascript

In my JavaScript code I am creating a URL to redirect my page to.  It works fine, but when I run it through the Fortify Scan, it gives me the following error:

The method reloadParentTab() sends unvalidated data to a web browser on line (line number), which can result in the browser executing malicious code.

I've added a URL validator and ran the newly created URL through it, however, the error is still present.
Now, this is what it looks like now:

```
//This is reloadParentTab function, mentioned above
function reloadParentTab() {    
        if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {     //checks if parent tab is present
            //here we check a variable, irrelevant here, except that it decides whether we
            //run window.opener.location.reload() or specify the URL, which is what the scan
            //complains about
            if (someTriggerValid()) {                                                                             
                var href = window.opener.location.href;      //This is the source
                if (validURL(href)) {                        // running the validator
                    //building the new URL
                    var newHref = href.substring(0, href.indexOf("tracking.")) + 
                        "tracking.base.open.request.do?dataObjectKey=object.dsaidCase&trackingId=" + caseId;                
                    //running the new URL through the validator, just to show that I tried it both ways
                    if (validURL(newHref)) {
                        //this is "Sink", that's where unvalidated data is, supposedly, sent, 
                        //although I am validating it 
                        window.opener.location.href = newHref;  
                    }
                }
            } else {
                window.opener.location.reload();    
            }           
        }
}

//And this is the validator
function validURL(str) {
    var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
        '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
        '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
        '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
        '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
        '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator
    return !!pattern.test(str);
}
```

So my question is: what am I missing and what else do I need to do to get this resolved?  Any ideas are welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: You can implement `validURL` in a safer way using the `URL` constructor: `function validURL(str) { try { new URL(str); return true; } catch(err) { return false; } }`. About the issue: the scanner isn't perfect, so it might be a false positive.

Comment: In this case, I can make validator safer, like you suggested, and make sure that the scanner will bypass it?  Is it actually possible to do that?  Is there a way to watch for false positives?

Comment: Does the scanner have a working exploit?

Comment: Don't know about that.  It should, but I'm not certain.

Comment: In my experience with fortify they checker often makes mistakes and gives a lot of false positives.  I'm not sure if there is a way to watch for false positives but usually you can just mark it as such, but ready to explain why it's a false positive.